# How do i display django class based view api on bootstrap template?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-templates, django-class-based-views

I am working on a photography website and i have created a rest api for blog but i am facing trouble how to display the api on template.

My project structure
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M2j2w.png)

This is my view.py of Blog

```
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import permissions
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView
from blog.models import BlogPost
from blog.serializers import BlogPostSerializer
from rest_framework.renderers import TemplateHTMLRenderer

class BlogPostListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-date_created')
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )

class BlogPostDetailView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-date_created')
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )

class BlogPostFeaturedView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all().filter(featured=True)
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer
    lookup_field = 'slug'
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )

class BlogPostCategoryView(APIView):
    serializer_class = BlogPostSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )

    def post(self, request, format=None):
        data = self.request.data
        category = data['category']
        queryset = BlogPost.objects.order_by('-date_created').filter(category__iexact=category)

        serializer = BlogPostSerializer(queryset, many=True)

        return Response(serializer.data)
```

This is urls.py of Blog

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import BlogPostListView, BlogPostDetailView, BlogPostFeaturedView, BlogPostCategoryView
urlpatterns = [
    path('', BlogPostListView.as_view(), name='bl'),
    path('featured', BlogPostFeaturedView.as_view()),
    path('category', BlogPostCategoryView.as_view()),
    path('<slug>', BlogPostDetailView.as_view()),
]
```

This urls.py of application

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include
from django.views.generic import TemplateView
from portfolio import urls, views
from blog import urls
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', views.index, name = 'index'),
    path('portfolio/', include('portfolio.urls')),
    path('gallery/', views.gallery, name = 'gallery'),
    path('shop/', views.shop, name = 'shop'),
    path('photo/<str:pk>', views.viewPhoto, name = 'photo'),
    path('add/', views.addPhoto, name = 'add'),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls')),
    path('summernote/', include('django_summernote.urls')),
    path('blog/', include('blog.urls')),
]

urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Rest api for Blog is working, how do use the rest api to display on blog.html??

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i95Xt.png)

Comment: Well, you will need to somehow make a request on from your api. You can use a frontend framework with bootstrap installed on it or you can use django itself to display the frontend with its template system but with a different approach.

Comment: can you please share any link where i can learn how to use django itself to display the frontend.